# Issue in Understanding the Boundary Conditions for European Call Option in Implicit Finite Difference Method

Tags: programming, european-options, finite-difference-method

I have a working Python code which prices European call option in Implicit Finite Difference setting. However, I am unable to understand the Boundary Conditions implemented on the coefficient matrix as mentioned in the code. Any help regarding the same will be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg 

#parameters
S0 = 95
K = 60 #ATM Strike
r = 0.01
T = 0.5
vol = 0.2
Smax = 100
M = 6  # S
N = 6 # t
is_call = True

def Implicit_FDM(S0, K, r, T, vol, Smax, M, N, is_call=True):
    
    M, N = int(M), int(N)
    dt = T / float(N)
    iVal = np.arange(1, M)
    jVal = np.arange(N)
    grid = np.zeros(shape=(M+1, N+1))
    SValues = np.linspace(0, Smax, M+1)
    alpha =  0.5*dt * (r *iVal - vol**2 *iVal**2)
    beta  =  1+dt * (r + vol**2 * iVal**2)
    gamma = -0.5*dt * (r * iVal + vol**2 * iVal**2)
    
    # Coefficient or Tridiagonal Matrix
    coeff = np.diag(alpha[1:], -1) + np.diag(beta) + np.diag(gamma[:-1], 1)
    
    # Terminal Condition
    if is_call:
        grid[:, -1] = np.maximum(SValues - K, 0)
    else:
        grid[:, -1] = np.maximum(K - SValues, 0)
    
    # Boundary conditions
    coeff[0, 0] = coeff[0, 0] + 2*alpha[0]
    coeff[0, 1] = coeff[0, 1] - alpha[0]
    coeff[-1, -1] = coeff[-1, -1] + 2*gamma[-1]
    coeff[-1, -2] = coeff[-1, -2] - gamma[-1]
    
    # Matrix Decomposition
    P, L, U = scipy.linalg.lu(coeff)
    
    for j in reversed(jVal):
         Ux = scipy.linalg.solve(L, grid[1:-1, j+1])
         grid[1:-1, j] = scipy.linalg.solve(U, Ux)
         grid[0, j] = 2 * grid[1, j] - grid[2, j]
         grid[-1, j] = 2 * grid[-2, j] -grid[-3, j]
         
    return np.interp(S0,SValues,grid[:, 1])

#print the value
print(Implicit_FDM(S0, K, r, T, vol, Smax, M, N, is_call=True))
```

Comment: Hi. Any update regarding the same will be greatly appreciated!!. Thanks!!

Comment: At first look it would amount to imposing a zero gamma condition at the boundaries (no convexity)

Comment: @Quantuple: But the Boundary conditions for european options means we have S =0 and S = infinity?

Comment: I don't understand your sentence. Boundary conditions means you impose condition on the function you are solving for at some boundaries. Whether this is that you know the value of the function at these points (Dirichlet condition) or the value of its derivative (Neumann condition) is up to you

Comment: Note that it's very weird that you choose Smax = 100 while your spot is at 95, you should pick a higher value (to emulate condition at infinity)